# Trying to use Object Oriented code to display database information

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to use Object Oriented code to display users (management) in a database, The variables are loaded with the right info for connection, My DB code is

```
/* Code to Connect to the Database */
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password);
if($mysqli->connect_errno){
    echo "Failed to connect to the Database: " . $mysql->connect_error;
}
```

and the code i'm using to display the users is

```
$query = ("SELECT m_username, m_email, m_fname, m_sname, m_mccode, m_mobile FROM management");

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

/* fetch associative array */
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
printf ($row["m_username"], $row["m_email"], $row["m_fname"], $row["m_sname"],               $row["m_mccode"], $row["m_mobile"]);
}
/* Frees the result set */
$result->close();
/* Close the Connection */
$mysqli->close();
}
```

When I go to the page that has this code, I get nothing displayed and there is users in the DB.

Comment: Database not selected. Change `mysqli_connect()` arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided database name, so database not selected. Change `mysqli_connect()` arguments:

```
$db = 'mydbname';

$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db);
```

Also, you may try to add MySQL debug messages, while *testing* your scripts:

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        printf ($row["m_username"], $row["m_email"], $row["m_fname"], $row["m_sname"], $row["m_mccode"], $row["m_mobile"]);
    }

    /* Frees the result set */
    $result->close();
} else {
    /* Show error message */
    echo $mysqli->error;
}

/* Close the Connection */
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I thought i had put the Database Var in there.